# WordPress Remove Woocommerce variation animation slide down

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, product-variations

I would like to remove the default WordPress woocommerce cart slide down and up when selecting the different product variations.

As you can see on [this page](https://demo.woothemes.com/storefront/product/small-mp3-player-pro/) 
when you select any variation the price and add to cart button slides down and I would like to keep it always extended, basically remove the animation.

as far as I know, all themes have this like this.

Thanks.

Comment: have you found a solution fot that?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to disable this animation as well. Luckily, there are some custom events that are triggered just as the animation happens, so I was able to cancel the animation and just show/hide the variation prices:

**Disable animation for variation prices:**

```js
$(document).on('show_variation', '.cart.variations_form', (e) => {
  let hasText = !!$.trim($('.woocommerce-variation.single_variation').text())
  $('.woocommerce-variation.single_variation').stop().removeAttr('style').toggle(hasText)
}).on('hide_variation', (e) => {
  $('.woocommerce-variation.single_variation').stop().hide()
})
```

Having the price always show is a bit more difficult, because the entire element is empty until a variant has been selected. One option is to move the general price block (the "£49.99 – £99.95") down alongside the variation price (by removing the action in PHP `remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10)` and re-adding it somewhere else. Then you can toggle this block in the Javascript based on the visibility of the variation price block.